# SQL Server - Unable to run cursor FETCH statement dynamically stored in variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've a cursor which fetch dynamic number of columns because the "SELECT STATEMENT" which I use to declare this cursor is dynamic.

Since I do not know at any point of time, how many columns this cursor will have, I cannot declare fixed number of variables into fetch.

So I have built FETCH statement as dynamic and stored in one @variable... but when i run fetch statement using EXEC sp_executesql 
its failing with error ..Must declare the scalar variable "@objcursor".

I know that @objcursor variable is not accessible becasue while sp_executesql run which run on isolate THREAD

is there any way someone can advise, how to handle this code to run without an error?

Here is my T-SQL code:

```
/* ==== Variable Declaration ==== */
    declare @AllValues nvarchar(max)
    declare @objcursor as cursor             
    declare @MonthCount integer 
    declare 
        @vsql        as nvarchar(max)
        ,@vquery    as nvarchar(max)
        ,@id        as int
        ,@value        as varchar(50)

    BEGIN               
        SELECT @AllValues = CASE 
            WHEN t.column_id=1 THEN 
            (COALESCE(@AllValues +'"', '')+ t.name)+'"'
                WHEN t.column_id > 1 THEN 
                (COALESCE(@AllValues + ',"', '') + t.name)+'"' 
                END
            FROM
            (
                SELECT sc.name, sc.column_id FROM sys.objects o
                INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON o.object_id = sc.object_id
                WHERE o.name = 'temp_daywise' AND o.type = 'U' AND (sc.name like '%Curr Yr%'  or column_id=1)

            ) AS t
            ORDER BY t.column_id
            SET @AllValues='SELECT  "'+@AllValues+' FROM dbo.temp_daywise'

            set @vquery = @AllValues
            set @vsql = 'set @cursor = cursor forward_only static for ' + @vquery + ' open @cursor;'

            exec sys.sp_executesql
                @vsql
                ,N'@cursor cursor output'
                ,@objcursor output

            ---Handling Dynamic number of columns in a cursor, get the column count first and build FETCH statement dynamically
            Select @CurCount=COUNT(*) from sys.columns where object_id in(  
                SELECT object_id from sys.objects where name = 'dbo.temp_daywise' and type = 'U'    )
                    and (name like '%Curr Yr%');
            SET @LoopCount = 1      
            --here building my fetch statement
            SET @fetchsql  ='fetch next from @objcursor into @AgreementID'                          
            WHILE @LoopCount <= @CurCount
                BEGIN
                    SET @fetchsql = @fetchsql+','+'@CY_Day'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@LoopCount)                  
                    SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
                END             
                --EXEC @fetchsql 

                EXEC sp_executesql @fetchsql 

            while (@@fetch_status = 0)
            begin
                BEGIN       
                    'update ...here something'
                END     
            EXEC @fetchsql                          
            end
            close @objcursor
            deallocate @objcursor       
    END
```

### Here is my data and expected resullts:

1) My dynamic cusror will read column name from sys.columns because coulmns are not static that's based on columns count I'm building FETCH statement. following code build cusrsor SELECT statement

```
SELECT @AllValues = CASE 
                WHEN t.column_id=1 THEN 
                (COALESCE(@AllValues +'"', '')+ t.name)+'"'
                    WHEN t.column_id > 1 THEN 
                    (COALESCE(@AllValues + ',"', '') + t.name)+'"' 
                    END
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT sc.name, sc.column_id FROM sys.objects o
                    INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON o.object_id = sc.object_id
                    WHERE o.name = 'temp_daywise' AND o.type = 'U' AND (sc.name like '%Curr Yr%'  or column_id=1)

                ) AS t
                ORDER BY t.column_id
                SET @AllValues='SELECT  "'+@AllValues+' FROM dbo.temp_daywise'

                set @vquery = @AllValues
                set @vsql = 'set @cursor = cursor forward_only static for ' + @vquery + ' open @cursor;'

                exec sys.sp_executesql
                    @vsql
                    ,N'@cursor cursor output'
                    ,@objcursor output
```

2) I want to update fetch data into following table for columns Day1...Day31. if cusrsor found 20 columns data will update until CY_Day20.

[image]

3) In short, i do not know the cusror retrieving columns at design time so i can't produce fetching variable. Since columns are known at run tiume, i have to build fetch & update statment in while loop as like below:

Note: ignore DECLARE which is on start of the code... but i placed here to get an idea.

```
DECLARE 
   @CY_Day1 Numeric(18,2), @CY_Day2 Numeric(18,2), @CY_Day3 Numeric(18,2), @CY_Day4 Numeric(18,2), @CY_Day5 Numeric(18,2), 
  , @CY_Day7 Numeric(18,2), @CY_Day8 Numeric(18,2), @CY_Day9 Numeric(18,2), @CY_Day10 Numeric(18,2), @PY_Day10 Numeric(18,2), @CY_Day11 Numeric(18,2), @CY_Day12 Numeric(18,2),........ @CY_Day31 Numeric(18,2)

        Select @CurCount=COUNT(*) from sys.columns where object_id in(  
                SELECT object_id from sys.objects where name = 'dbo.temp_daywise' and type = 'U'    )
                    and (name like '%Curr Yr%');
            SET @LoopCount = 1      
            SET @fetchsql  ='fetch next from @objcursor into @AgreementID'              
            SET @updatesql ='UPDATE  dbo.TPDD_Report_Monthly_Details SET ' 
            WHILE @LoopCount <= 2
                BEGIN
                    SET @fetchsql = @fetchsql+','+'@CY_Day'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@LoopCount)                  
                    SET @updatesql= @updatesql +'CY_Day'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@LoopCount)+' = @CY_Day'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@LoopCount)+',CY_TPDD_Day'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@LoopCount)+' = (@CY_Day'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@LoopCount)+'/1/1),'
                    SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
                END
                SET @updatesql =@updatesql  + ' dss_update_time = @v_dss_update_time WHERE AgreementId =  @AgreementID and TpddYear=CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@Current_year)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@Previous_year) and Running_Month = @MonthNo'
                --EXEC @fetchsql 
                PRINT @fetchsql 
                PRINT @updatesql

                ---executing FETCH statement 
                EXEC sp_executesql @fetchsql 

            while (@@fetch_status = 0)
            begin
                BEGIN       
                    ---updating table columns
                    EXEC sp_executesql @updatesql               
                END     
            EXEC @fetchsql                          
            end
            close @objcursor
            deallocate @objcursor
```

Finally my cusrsor fetch & udpate statement will looks like below:

```
fetch next from @objcursor into     @AgreementID,@CY_Day1,@CY_Day2,@CY_Day3,@CY_Day4,@CY_Day5,@CY_Day6,@CY_Day7,@CY_Day8,@CY_Day9,@CY_Day10

    UPDATE  dbo.TPDD_Report_Monthly_Details SET 
                                CY_Day1 = @CY_Day1, CY_TPDD_Day1 = (@CY_Day1/1/1),              
                                CY_Day2 = @CY_Day2, CY_TPDD_Day2 = (@CY_Day2/1/1),              
                                CY_Day3 = @CY_Day3, CY_TPDD_Day3 = (@CY_Day3/1/1),              
                                CY_Day4 = @CY_Day4, CY_TPDD_Day4 = (@CY_Day4/1/1),              
                                CY_Day5 = @CY_Day5, CY_TPDD_Day5 = (@CY_Day5/1/1),      
                                CY_Day6 = @CY_Day6, CY_TPDD_Day6 = (@CY_Day6/1/1),  
                                CY_Day7 = @CY_Day7, CY_TPDD_Day7 = (@CY_Day7/1/1),                              
                                CY_Day8 = @CY_Day8, CY_TPDD_Day8 = (@CY_Day8/1/1),                                  
                                CY_Day9 = @CY_Day9, CY_TPDD_Day9 = (@CY_Day9/1/1),
                                CY_Day10 = @CY_Day10, CY_TPDD_Day10 = (@CY_Day10/1/1),                          
                                dss_update_time = @v_dss_update_time                                        
                        WHERE AgreementId =  @AgreementID
```

Hope I;m able to present my problem correctly.

Comment: When you execute a dynamic sql statement, it's in a different scope so it doesn't work the same. If you want to stick to a cursor, then you're going to have your entire cursor in your execute statement, which can get quite tricky. If you want, post some sample data and your desired results, and I would be glad to help you come up with a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I've added expected results and data with my problem statement. Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I have a good start. You're probably going to have to tweak a few things. I did my best to get it as close as possible as your actual situation. Hope this helps. If you have any questions, let me know.

### NOTE I USE THE SAME TABLE NAMES AND DROP THEM.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.temp_daywise') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.temp_daywise;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TPDD_report_Monthly_Details') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.TPDD_report_Monthly_Details;

CREATE TABLE dbo.temp_daywise
(
    AgreementID CHAR(6),
    RunningMonth INT,
    [Curr Yr1] VARCHAR(100),
    [Curr Yr2] VARCHAR(100),
    [Curr Yr3] VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO temp_daywise
VALUES  ('A10001',3,'col1_1','col2_1','col3_1'),
        ('A10003',3,'col1_2','col2_2','col3_2'),
        ('A10006',3,'col1_3','col2_3','col3_3'),
        ('A10008',3,'col1_4','col2_4','col3_4');

CREATE TABLE dbo.TPDD_report_Monthly_Details
(
    TpddYear DATE,
    AgreementID CHAR(6),
    RunningMonth INT,
    [CY_Day1] VARCHAR(100),
    [CY_Day2] VARCHAR(100),
    [CY_Day3] VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO TPDD_report_Monthly_Details
VALUES  ('20131220','A10001',3,NULL,NULL,NULL),
        ('20131220','A10003',3,NULL,NULL,NULL),
        ('20131220','A10006',3,NULL,NULL,NULL),
        ('20131220','A10008',3,NULL,NULL,NULL);

--Now that I've created my versions of your table, here's the actual code

--Variable to hold columns that need to be updated
DECLARE @ColToBeUpdated VARCHAR(MAX);

--Gets your column information for temp_daywise
WITH CTE_temp_daywise_Cols
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'temp_daywise'
)

--Now join temp_daywise columns to TPDD_report columns
    --QUOTENAME() add's brackets [] around each column
SELECT  @ColToBeUpdated = COALESCE(@ColToBeUpdated + ',','') + QUOTENAME(A.COLUMN_NAME) + ' = B.' + QUOTENAME(B.COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A
INNER JOIN CTE_temp_daywise_Cols B
    --The "+1" compensates for difference in ordinal positions
    ON A.Ordinal_Position  = B.ORDINAL_POSITION + 1
--This makes the table alisaed A to only get columns for TPDD_report
WHERE   A.TABLE_NAME = 'TPDD_report_Monthly_Details'
        --Don't return AgreementID
        AND A.COLUMN_NAME != 'AgreementID'
        AND B.COLUMN_NAME != 'AgreementID'
ORDER BY A.ORDINAL_POSITION

--Variable to hold code
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @sql =  'UPDATE  dbo.TPDD_Report_Monthly_Details 
                SET ' + @ColToBeUpdated +'
                FROM dbo.TPDD_Report_Monthly_Details AS A
                INNER JOIN temp_daywise AS B
                ON A.AgreementID = B.AgreementID'

--Look at code
--Notice you can join on AgreementID and just set the columns equal to each other
SELECT @sql;

--To execute
--EXEC(@sql)
```

Results stored in @sql:

```
UPDATE  dbo.TPDD_Report_Monthly_Details 
    SET [RunningMonth] = B.[RunningMonth],
        [CY_Day1] = B.[Curr Yr1],
        [CY_Day2] = B.[Curr Yr2],
        [CY_Day3] = B.[Curr Yr3]
    FROM dbo.TPDD_Report_Monthly_Details AS A
    INNER JOIN temp_daywise AS B
    ON A.AgreementID = B.AgreementID
```

Comment: Glad to help! And feel free to mark mine as the correct answer so people know it worked.